# Counter Expansion in newcommand

Tags: macros, counters, expl3, expansion, forms

I am trying to create a pdf form. As far as I understood the documentation every checkbox has to have a unique name. If all checkboxes have the same name all of them will be checked at once. I want the name to be automatically generated. I tried the following code:

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{uncompress,pdfversion=2.0}
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{l3pdffield-testphase}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{namecounter}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\mcheckb}[2]{%
    \pdffield_checkbox:n{name=#2\thenamecounter,checked=false,width=#1,height=#1}%
    \stepcounter{namecounter}
}
\newcommand{\rating}[2]{\setcounter{namecounter}{0}\hfill\prg_replicate:nn {5}{\mcheckb{#1}{#2}\hspace{.2cm}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\Form[NeedAppearances=false] 
First line with multiple checkboxes \rating{0.5cm}{first}\\
Second line with multiple checkboxes \rating{0.5cm}{second}\\
\end{document}
```

The counter doesn't seem to be expanded correctly.

I want that the checkboxes have the following names:
first1 first2 ...
second1 second2 ...

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: hm, full expansion is probably not a good idea, but I should perhaps expand the name once, then you could predefine a command. Perhaps make a feature request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to expand `\thenamecounter` before `\pdffield_checkbox:n` absorbs the argument.

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{uncompress,pdfversion=2.0}

\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{l3pdffield-testphase}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{namecounter}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\mcheckb}{mm}
 {
  \stepcounter{namecounter}
  \exp_args:Ne \pdffield_checkbox:n
   {
    name=#2\thenamecounter,
    checked=false,
    width=#1,
    height=#1
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\rating}{mm}
 {
  \setcounter{namecounter}{0}
  \hfill\prg_replicate:nn {5}{\mcheckb{#1}{#2}\hspace{.2cm}}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\Form[NeedAppearances=false] 

First line with multiple checkboxes \rating{0.5cm}{first}

Second line with multiple checkboxes \rating{0.5cm}{second}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The picture shows that the boxes can be checked independently on one another.